# VLCJ - Marquee not showing

Tags: java, swing, vlcj

I am trying to add a marquee to a VLCJ Media Player. However whenever I start the MediaPlayer I can not see the Marquee anywhere.

For reference I have been following the tutorial on the following link: http://capricasoftware.co.uk/#/projects/vlcj/tutorial/marquee

The code for setting up the JFrame can be found below.

```
final MediaPlayerComponent mediaPlayerComponent = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent();
add(mediaPlayerComponent);

setVisible(true);

Marquee.marquee()
.text("Marquee!")
.size(20)
.colour(Color.white)
.opacity(0.7f)
.position(libvlc_marquee_position_e.centre)
.location(5,5)
.timeout(5000)
.enable()
.apply(mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer());

mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().prepareMedia(WORKING_DIR + "view.mp4");
```

Note: WORKING_DIR is a static String that contains the current working directory path.

After setup, when a play button is pressed the play method on the mediaplayer is called.

I feel like I have done everything that the tutorial says to do, and all of my online searches have come up fruitless. If anyone can help it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you must wait until the media player has actually started playing before you can set the marquee.

Check if the `MarqueeTest` in the vlcj sources works for you.

Comment: I came to the conclusion that I felt it was a problem with VLC itself. Even when using VLC Media Player directly I couldn't just add a Marquee threw the preferences, I had to add a text effect, which seems to turn marquees on and then I could change the marquee setting in the preferences. For reference I'm using VLC Media Player 2.2.4. In the end I repurporsed your overlay example to recreate a text overlay that I could enable/disable